# XSLT apply templates select condition on node list

Tags: xpath, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have an xml with a list and wanted to apply template on that which will send only specific nodes by a condition, but it is applying on the whole list. Could someone if I am missing anything, I am relatively new to XSL.
The condition I wanted to apply is if dep is 7 and no city tag exists, I started with condition to check if dep is 7. After apply template if i print my list, it is getting all of them, Instead of dep just with value 7.In my output I expect not to have dep with value 9.

**Input XML:**

```
<employeeList>

  <employee>
    <dep>7</dep>
    <salary>900</salary>
  </employee>

  <employee>
    <dep>7</dep>
    <city>LA</city>
    <salary>500</salary>
  </employee>

  <employee>
    <dep>9</dep>
    <salary>600</salary>
  </employee>

  <employee>
    <dep>7</dep>
    <salary>800</salary>
  </employee>

</employeeList>
```

**My XSL:**

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="employeeList[employee/dep = '7']" mode="e"/>

<xsl:template match="employeeList" mode="e">
       <xsl:for-each select="employee">
           <dep>
               <xsl:value-of select="dep" />
           </dep>
       </xsl:for-each>
```

**Output XML:**

```
<dep>7</dep><dep>7</dep><dep>9</dep><dep>7</dep>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add (1) a complete, executable stylesheet and (2) the exact output you expect to get - see: ]mcve].

Answer (score 1):

> The condition I wanted to apply is if dep is 7 and no city tag exists

Such condition can be easily implemented using e.g.:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/employeeList">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="employee[dep='7' and not(city)]">
            <dep>7</dep>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or shortly:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/employeeList">
    <root>
        <xsl:copy-of select="employee[dep='7' and not(city)]/dep"/>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it's hard to see the point in outputting  X number of `<dep>7</dep>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

You select the `employeeList` based on a condition on its `employee/dep`, but once you have selected it, that condition no longer matters, and the `<xsl:for-each select="employee">` selects all `employee`s, regardless of their `dep`.

You can repeat the condition in the `xsl:for-each` statement:

```xml
<xsl:for-each select="employee[dep = '7']">
```

Comment: Why would it be necessary to repeat the condition?